# matplotlib and pyqt6 give ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt6

I tried to update my code from pyqt5 to pyqt6. I changed nothing else but now I keep getting

```
ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding
```

I could not find any question or solution that actually involved pyqt6 so therefore I post this question here. I did a few simple checks. I can import pyqt6 and I can also import matplotlib.pyplot The error seems to originate from:

```
lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py
```

It looks a little weird to me to use qt5 here but this is what i found in this tutorial https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt6-plotting-matplotlib/

any ideas, or things that I could check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following solved this issue.

After an update of matplotlib I changed the importline saying:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import ...
```

to

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import ...
```

that fixed my error